# Prevent "DOT" for Input type number in Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-mobile, cordova

am working With jQueryMobile with PhoneGap..
Currently I have an issue.. I search about it but didnt get an exact reply. 
My problem is i want to prevent the typing DOT in Textbox. Textbox is for enter AGE.

```
<input type="number" class="form_textbox_half" data-role="none" id="age" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

**And Its Keypress event ;**

```
$('#age').live('keypress', function(){preventDot(event)});
```

**Then its Function is**

```
function preventDot(event) {
    alert(0);
    //var test = document.getElementById("#age");
    var key = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
    $("#age").innerHTML = key;
    if (key == 46) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But its not works.. I want to prevent typing DOT in the textbox.
I think its a small issue.. :( 
But didnt get a solution for it.. please help me!

Comment: Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41227274/2471497) that I've posted recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed your issue

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8yNeP/)

The problem was that you were not using [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) to stop the propogation of the `keypress` event

This is how the modified method looks:

```
function preventDot(event)
{
    alert(event.charCode)
    //var test = document.getElementById("#age");
    var key = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;  
    $("#age").innerHTML = key;
    if (key == 46)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Not working on mobile devices. Keypress event itself is not firing when you click dot in mobile device. :(

Answer (score 2):

I found only this to work

```
$(".vinput").on("input change paste",
function filterNumericAndDecimal(event) {
    var formControl;
    formControl = $(event.target);
    var newtext = formControl.val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
    formControl.val(''); //without this the DOT wont go away on my phone!
    formControl.val(newtext);
});
```

but if you need the dot included use [^0-9.] as regex

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code i solve with this currentlly

```
function bindOnInputQuantity() {    
    $('.receiveQty').blur('input', function() {
    var sel = $(this);
    var selDel = $(this).next();
    if(sel.val() === '') {
        sel.val(0);
        sel.data('current', 0);
    } else {
        if(parseInt(sel.val()) > parseInt(selDel.val())) {
            alert('Receive Quantity Cannot More Then Delivery Quantity!');
            sel.val(sel.data('current'));
            sel.focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            sel.val(parseInt(sel.val()));
            sel.data('current', sel.val());
        }            
      }        
   });}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
$('#age').live('keypress', function(event){preventDot(event)});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/8yNeP/1/)

Comment: That doesn't stop characters from being entered with the code supplied.

Comment: Without passing a event as parameter. You can do that function

Comment: Replacing only that line of code in the original question code does not prevent you from typing the full-stop. You've modified the code from the original question a lot more than just that line, so your answer, in the context you provided, doesn't work.