# Restrict the user entering period in input field on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I want to restrict the user from entering special character in a number field on an Android device.  The "." (dot) character is not passing values in an "onkeypress" event, as expected.

With `<input type="text">` I can able to block the user from entering any special character.

But with `<input type="number"/>` I am not able to restrict the user from entering dot key.

Tried with many stack overflow posts. But still no luck.

Below is the code i am trying:

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="registrationField.mobilenumber" tabindex="0" no-special-character="^[0-9-]*$" >
```

**JS**

```
app.directive("noSpecialCharacter", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
            var regex = RegExp(attrs.noSpecialCharacter);
            angular.element(elem).on("keydown", function(e) {
                if(e.key == "Unidentified"){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

I am using `keydown` event because `keypress` event is not triggering on press of dot key in number keypad.

Also, I am receiving the `e.key` as `Unidentified` when user has entered the dot key. So i am trying to manipulate with it.

I have tried with trimming the last value when the user has entered the dot key and that is also not working.

Please suggest any possible way.

Tried the above code in `Android Nexus 5X` device.

Comment: If you're trying to achieve input validation for a phone number, don't try to use `input[type=number]`. Its meant for actual numbers. Then try using input masks instead

Comment: @Eddi I understand. But the client want to use only the number keypad. Is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Have you tried the input `type=tel`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know this is a bad solution since it uses the `$timeout` service but at least anything after fighting this all day long..

First of all set the type to `type="tel"` (don't know why but the same doesn't work with `type="number"`) register the on-change event:

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="$ctrl.numberField" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" />
```

Then in your controller inject the angular `$timeout` service and define the `onChange()` function:

```
onChange() {
    // the below code is relevant for Android platform in cordova
    if (typeof cordova != 'undefined' && cordova.platformId == "android") {
        // filter all available input characters in Android NumPad mode
        var r = new RegExp("[#/;,N\(\)\.\*\-]");
        if (r.test(this.data)) {
            // perform the filter after the digest cycle of angular is complete
            this.$timeout(() => {
                this.data = this.data.replace(r, "");
          }, 100);
     }
}
```

All the weird characters you see in the `RegExp` object are those that Android can place in the NumberPad state of its keyboard.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I didn't understood question correctly, this solution will not work on mobile devices, this is plain javascript solution for input field.

```
<div>
<input onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' type="number" placeholder="Input Value" />
</div>
```

Here is working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/16784/

Comment: Above answer is working fine in fiddle. But as I mentioned in my question, the keypress event is not triggered when i entered the dot key from number keypad in android device.

Comment: Actually, while you do state that the issue is on Android; it's NOT clear in the question that the "Android dot key" is the behavior you are having issues with.

Comment: The answer does not answer the question. The question is about entering the period/dot sign in Android and the answer doesn't work for it. The Fiddle is not relevant since the answer should be tested in Android environment.

Comment: Yea that's true, my bad i didn't understood question properly, i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround using input number, jQuery and setTimeout:

```
<input type="number" name="test" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" step="1" class="only-numbers" />


$(document).on('keydown', '.only-numbers', function (e) {
    var inputElement = $(this);
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            inputElement.attr('type', 'text').attr('type', 'number');
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

You might need to adjust the setTimeout delay if it doesn't work.

I hope it helps someone who is having the same annoying issue.